# With Keras, Can I Include Code to Remove Certain Training Samples During Training That is Dependent on the Prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am using a u-net built using keras. I would like to exclude certain training examples when a special case condition is met. For example, if a truth value is `a < threshold` and the predicted value is `b < threshold`, then exclude this example from training. I want to use a modified version of MAE that adds an extra "incorrectness" during training when the values enter some "specially serious" category that will be penalized more heavily.

Comment: To get the predicted value from a NN, we need to pass a particular example to NN. If this example has already been fed to the NN, how can we remove it from the training set?

Comment: You may consider asking the question on the [TensorFlow Forum](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/).